# Model binding not working for List<T> T in case of Web api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a action method with HTTP Verb: POST which accepts `List<Student>` student object from body as one of the input parameter of the action method:

```
[Route("{Id:int}/save", Name = "SaveStudent")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult AddStudent(int Id,[FromBody]List<Student> students)
{
   return Ok<List<Student>>(students);
}
```

Now when I tried to test the above method from the Fiddler using the below request details:

{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "Test",
      "rollno": null,
      "totalmarks": null
    }
  ]
}

I am getting a 400 bad request error.
Can anyone help me to know what exactly I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array is not in correct format it should be like this:

```
[{name: "Test", rollno: null, totalmarks: null }, {name: "Test2", rollno: null, totalmarks: null }]
```

Model class used in C#

```
  public class Student {
public string Name { get; set; }
public int RollNo { get; set; }
public int TotalMarks { get; set; }
```

}

Additional json format resolver added during webapi initialization.

```
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

  var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
  jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

I hope this will help you getting this working now

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the above but still I am getting a 400 bad request error.

Comment: I have just checked it and it is working fine. I am adding details of Student model class used in my code. Also, you are passing values in camel casing which is used in java script but dot net we use pascal casing so that can be one reason. I have used additional formatter to support that.